# how do I send server response to POST request back to browser?

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, stm32

I am working on an embedded STM32 httpd project. I have part of the project working with html code using the GET method. I am able to accomplish the tasks I need to run using that method.

Now I want to require a username and password in order to access the GET page. I want to use the POST method so the UN and PW do not display in the URL bar. I have this code for submitting the username and password to the server.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>Login</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <form action="" method="post">
      <p>
        <input type="text" id="txtUsername" name="username" placeholder="Enter username" require/>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="password" id="txtPassword" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password" required/>
      </p>
      <br>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

I have breakpoints set in the server code and the UN and PW are received by the server. I am able to compare the UN and PW to the stored credentials on the server to see if they match. If they match I want to be able to send "good" back to the browser and "bad" if they don't match. I have this code working but don't know how to get the response back to the browser.

I have spent time online reading about javascript, ajax, and xhttp online. I have figued out I need to use a script to capture the response from the server. I have no html experience other than very basic. I found this example from w3schools.com.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h1>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Request data</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
 
<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "demo_post2.asp", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I run the sample code on the w3schools site, it returns "Hello Henry Ford". When I run it on my project board with breakpoints set, I see "fname=Henry" and "lastname=Ford" in the POST section of the server. But obviously I don't get any response. I assume the response on their site is from the "demo_post2.asp" program running on their server.

The STM32 httpd server only supports javacript, ajax, and xml. I do have CGI and SSI activated and working for the GET process. If the response from the POST is "good", I want to redirect the browser to another page on the server. If the response is "bad" I want to display a message "Bad username or password" and stay on the same login page.

Can someone direct me to a link or document that explains how to return data to the browser window?

luek, I do have SSI running and could use that. I think it is possible that the server returns char "*response_uri" to the browser when the post is finished. I am not sure about that but it appears to make sense due to the name.

Antoni, here is the code on the server. It is just plain vanilla C code.

```
err_t httpd_post_receive_data(void *connection, struct pbuf *p)
{
    // payload comes in as a string "username=username&password=password"
    char *ret, readval[48];
    char un[8], pw[24]; // pw is size 24 to allow for several special characters
    char delim[2];
    uint8_t x = 0, y = 0, pos;

    strcpy(delim, "=");
    strcpy(readval, p->payload);
    ret = strstr(readval, delim);
    pos = ret - readval;
    pos++; // step past = character to username

    for(x = pos; x < 25; x++) // 25 is 9(x start) + 16(un size)
    {
      if(readval[x] == 0x26) // 0x26 is & character
        break;
      un[y] = readval[x];
      y++;
    }
    un[y] = '\0'; // add string terminate character

    x++; // step past & character
    pos = x + 9; // 9 is length of word "password" plus \0
    for(x = (pos-9); x < pos; x++)
    {
      if(readval[x] == 0x3D) // 0x3D is = character
        break;
    }

    y = 0;
    x++; // step past = character
    pos = x + 24; // 24 is size of pw
    for(x = (pos-24); x < pos; x++)
    {
      if(readval[x] == '\0')
        break;
      pw[y] = readval[x];
      y++;
    }
    pw[y] = '\0'; // add string terminate character

    // add code here to compare username and password to values stored
    // in EEPROM. For testing purposes, just copy "good" to postval
    strcpy(postval, "good"); // postval is a global variable

    pbuf_free(p);
    return ERR_OK;
}

void httpd_post_finished(void *connection, char *response_uri, u16_t response_uri_len)
{
    response_uri_len = strlen(postval); // postval is a global variable
    snprintf(response_uri, response_uri_len, postval); // return un and pw check result
    connection = NULL;
    asm("NOP");
}
```

Comment: You need to use a server-side language to get a response. If you tell me which you are using I may be able to answer your question.

Comment: If you supply the server code (not the passwords) it would be possible to give an answer

Comment: I added the code to my original post. I don't see a way to add it after other user's comments.